# Weird normals after applying baked normal map

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I created a sculpt, then retopologyzed it via Poly Build Tool and Shrinkwrap-Modifier. Now I'm trying to bake a normal map for the low-poly object but its really not looking like it should. The normal map looks *ok* to me, but every island of the uv-mesh looks totally diffrent in viewport and render. It looks to me a little like the normals were partially flipped, but I already recalculated them. So that should not be the problem, I guess. Maybe it is a Blender 2.8 problem. What do you think?

Here are some images:
[image: Overlapping Objects]
Overlapping Objects

[image: Normal map]
Normal map

[image: The strange result of the normal map]
The strange result of the normal map. Note that these are exactly the seams of my unwrap.

[image: High-poly (left) and low-poly (right)]
High-poly (left) and low-poly (right)

[image: Material nodes]
Material nodes

Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, now it works. The only thing I did differently from the other times was to disconnect the Image Texture Node and changing the Color Space to Non-Color **before** the baking. I can't change the Color Space afterwards, this is new in Blender 2.8.

Comment: I think the color space doesn't matter if you disconnect the node. What happened was you had some normals already, And you were baking one high poly with normals into low poly. Now that you disconnected the image texture, you're baking just high poly (with no normals, that is, with *"default"* normals being perpendicular to the faces) into the low poly. If you actually want to use the normal information, then connect it **and** use non-color. This is because if you load an image to Blender as color, it assumes sRGB and converts it to linear color space - distoring the normal information.